# kubeadm join times out on non-default NIC/IP

Tags: join, kubernetes, kubeadm, nic

I am trying to configure a K8s cluster on-prem and the servers are running Fedora CoreOS using multiple NICs.

I am configuring the cluster to use a non-default NIC - a bond which is defined with 2 interfaces. All servers can reach each-other over that interface and have HTTP + HTTPS connectivity to the internet.

kubeadm join hangs at:

```
I0513 13:24:55.516837   16428 token.go:215] [discovery] Failed to request cluster-info, will try again: Get https://${BOND_IP}:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

The relevant kubeadm init config looks like this:

```
[...]
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: ${BOND_IP}
  bindPort: 6443
nodeRegistration:
  kubeletExtraArgs:
    volume-plugin-dir: "/opt/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec/"
    runtime-cgroups: "/systemd/system.slice"
    kubelet-cgroups: "/systemd/system.slice"
    node-ip: ${BOND_IP}
  criSocket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
  name: master
  taints:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
[...]
```

The join config that am using looks like this:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: JoinConfiguration
discovery:
  bootstrapToken:
    token: ${TOKEN}
    caCertHashes:
    - "${SHA}"
    apiServerEndpoint: "${BOND_IP}:6443"
nodeRegistration:
  kubeletExtraArgs:
    volume-plugin-dir: "/opt/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec/"
    runtime-cgroups: "/systemd/system.slice"
    kubelet-cgroups: "/systemd/system.slice"
```

If I am trying to configure it using default eth0, it works without issues.

This is not a connectivity issue. The port test works fine:

```
# nc -s ${BOND_IP_OF_NODE} -zv ${BOND_IP_OF_MASTER} 6443
Ncat: Version 7.80 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to ${BOND_IP_OF_MASTER}:6443.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.01 seconds.
```

I suspect this happens due to kubelet listening on eth0, if so, can I change it to use a different NIC/IP?

LE: The eth0 connection has been cut off completely (cable out, interface down, connection down).
Now, when we init, if we choose port 0.0.0.0 for the kube-api it defaults to the bond, which we wanted initially:

```
kind: InitConfiguration
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 0.0.0.0
```

result:

```
[certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [emp-prod-nl-hilv-quortex19 kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.0.0.1 ${BOND_IP}]
```

I have even added the 6443 port in iptables for accept and it still times out.. All my CALICO pods are up and running (all pods for that matter in kube-system namespace)

LLE:

I have tested calico and weavenet and both show the same issue. The api-server is up and can be reached from the master using curl but it times out from the nodes.

LLLE:

On the premise that the kube-api is nothing but an HTTPS server, I have tried two options from the node that cannot reach it when doing the kubeadm join:

1. Ran a python3 simple http server over 6443 and WAS ABLE TO CONNECT from node
2. Ran an nginx pod and exposed it over another port as NodePort and WAS ABLE TO CONNECT from node

the node just cant reach the api-server on 6443 or any other port for that matter ....

what am i doing wrong...

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/113#issuecomment-273702311) already?

Comment: no, i would very much prefer to continue with kubeadm for sake of simplicity

Are there any configurations to be applied at the bond interface level perhaps? I just tried weave-net and it fails the same way when joining a node

Comment: OP from the github I sent is using kubeadm.

Comment: i've tested this further:

1. ran an alpine  POD on master
2. installed nc + openssh (POD can reach internet)
3. exec sh into POD and ran ping, nc + ssh to node that fails to join the cluster
RESULT:
alpine POD reaches the node that times out via PING, NC and SSH without issues.

Double checked the ip routes on the machines and bond config and everything is looking flawless.... 

Running out of ideas fast...

Comment: I have tested using python http.server and different ports, including 6443. The node that normally times out when doing the join, can curl it without issues

If i curl the api server, it just times out :/

Comment: Maybe related: Regarding _Fedora CoreOS using multiple NICs_, there is (or was) a bug causing non-deterministic names of network interfaces  https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/coreos@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/6IPTZL57Z5NLBMPYMXNVSYAGLRFZBLIP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause:

The interface used was in BOND of type ACTIVE-ACTIVE. This made it so kubeadm tried another interface from the 2 bonded, which was not in the same subnet as the IP of the advertised server apparently...

Using ACTIVE-PASSIVE did the trick and was able to join the nodes.

LE: If anyone knows why **kubeadm join** does not support **LACP** with **ACTIVE-ACTIVE bond** setups on **FEDORA COREOS** please advise here. Otherwise, if additional configurations are required, I would very much like to know what I have missed.